# maven intranet repository fail-over redirect

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have setup 'Artifactory' as intranet maven repository. I have question related to fail-over.

Project POM

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://mvn.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://mvn.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://mvn.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://mvn.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible to use fail-over repository? meaning.. if my intranet repository is down, then maven build should automatically use some other location or directly from maven central??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you expect your repository to be down, but falling back to maven central is a really bad idea. You loose all the benefits of using corporate repository, and don't even know about it, because there is no way to determine where your build took dependencies from.

If you are worried about the availability of your repository, you should establish HA environment with number of servers, replicated and backed up one by another.

If you are switching the environments and once you're in different environment the binary repository from the other intranet is not accessible anymore, you need to switch working with binary repository which is available in the new environment by using different profile, which will include different server urls (or maybe just a proxy to access the original server).

Anyhow - shade the maven central with your binary repository and don't use it as a backup.

Comment: This happens all the time.  Why would this be unexpected in any way?  It's MORE remarkable when the repository is UP.

Comment: You have something wrong with your setup. Huge companies like Oracle, CA, EMC, LinkedIn, Netflix and who's not depending all their development on Artifactory and it just solidly works for them. I believe it should work for you as well. Which version are you using?

Comment: The version's not the issue, the issue is I am at location A and the IT guys at location B can't seem to keep the power on, the machine plugged in, the network up, the firewall holes properly poked through, the IP addresses fixed, the service account not locked out etc.  The machine USED to be at location A, and I could turn it on and plug it in and fix or adjust it.  But sadly, no longer.   THank you for your expertise, and helping me.  I appear to have put myself into quite a bind.

Comment: The answer is yes, don't use the ID central for your corporate one.

Comment: If you did that see the edit on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545961/how-to-use-the-internet-for-maven-builds-instead-if-the-corporate-maven-reposit for how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If the artifacts cannot be found in the list of `<repositories/>`, Maven will automatically attempt to fallback to Maven Central.

Comment: This is not true. the central repository is shaded with artifactory, as it should be. There is no way this setup will reach maven-central. And that's a good thing.

Comment: it is true if you do not replace the repository with id "central"

Comment: In the example given, there is a repository with id "central", so in the context of this question it is not true.

Comment: The big issue here is having once used a central repo, is there any easy way to "unuse it", removing all local copies of artifact references that point to the now defunct repository, that are available on the internet, keeping local copies of anything that is NOT available online, and removing the bad repository values so you can build as though you had never been connected?

Comment: So the answer is don't use the id "central".  My experience is it's a minor miracle if the 10 systems I need to build and deploy are actually all up